# Cannot zoom small image in cropit.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cropit

After reading the documentation, I still didn't found the solution on how can I resize the image even if the image is small. But it is working on big images, but then again it is not working on small images. Please see my code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#image-cropper').cropit({
    'minZoom': 2,
    'allowDragNDrop': false,
    'smallImage': 'allow'
  });

});
```

```css
.cropit-preview{

  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<div id="image-cropper">
  <div class="cropit-preview"></div>
  
  <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input" />
  
  <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input" />
  <div class="select-image-btn">Select new image</div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropit/0.5.1/jquery.cropit.min.js"></script>
```

**Sample Image**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting max zoom 
[reference](https://github.com/scottcheng/cropit/issues/246)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#image-cropper').cropit({
    'minZoom': 2,
    'allowDragNDrop': false,
    'smallImage': 'allow',
    'maxZoom' : 5
  });

  $(document).on('click','.zoomOut',function(){
   changeZoom();
  });

  $(document).on('click','.zoomIn',function(){
   changeZoom(true);
  });

  function changeZoom(increase){
   var elm = $('#image-cropper');
   var zoom = elm.cropit('zoom');
    zoom = increase ? zoom + 0.05 : zoom - 0.05;
    elm.cropit('zoom', zoom);
  }

});
```

```css
.cropit-preview{

  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<div id="image-cropper">
  <div class="cropit-preview"></div>
  
  <button class="zoomOut">Zoom Out</button>
  <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input" />
  <button class="zoomIn">Zoom In</button>
  
  <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input" />
  
  <div class="select-image-btn">Select new image</div>
</div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropit/0.5.1/jquery.cropit.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is great, but the minZoom is affected, it is now not smooth and not more controllable when you upload a big image.

Comment: When you zoom the image, it is stoping and stoping, not the smooth zooming.

Comment: My other idea would be increase or decrease zoom little by little by adding zoom in and out buttons. ```cropitElm.cropit('zoom', cropitElm.cropit('zoom') + 0.05);```

Comment: Can you apply it in your answer?

Comment: @Jonjie I've added zoom in and zoom out and changed the maxZoom  to 5

Comment: This is a great idea.

Comment: Glad it helps :D